# Why doesn't the "Remember Me" checkbox work for me on a live website? Only works on a local server environment

Tags: login, cookies

If I check "Remember Me", and then log out, my login and password are **not** remembered. I've tested this on many WordPress sites running WP 3.2.1 on a server here in NZ and also on a completely different server hosted in the US. It doesn't appear to be a problem with just my browser, as quite a few people have tested this for me. Although I have tried clearing all cookies, cache etc.

It **does** however work locally with a MAMP setup on OS X. Is there something I need to install on the server to get this working? I presume it's using session cookies? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your browser settings. You can change the settings for size and time to keep the cookies.

Comment: I don't understand. If it's using session cookies, aren't they stored on the server? Doesn't make sense to me that WordPress would include a Remember Me checkbox that would never work, unless you remembered to update your browser's settings.

Comment: the cookies are stored in your browser. all the remember me checkbox does is extend the expiration time of the cookie from two days to two weeks. see [wp_set_auth_cookie](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) for more info.

Comment: If you had your browser settings set to allow cookies and they were set to never expire, you would still have to type the password + Username unless you selected the "remember me" check-box.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I think I have a better understanding of how it all works now.